# Regular expression to limit number of digits

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that will only match with *qtr1*, *qtr2*, *qtr3*, *qtr4* with help of following regex `[q|qtr|qtrs|quarter]+[1-4]` but the problem is if i ask something like this "Ficoscore for Q21 2005" a space is added between Q and 21 ie "Ficoscore for Q 21 2005" this not valid.

```
  String regEx = "([q|qtr|qtrs|quarter]+[1-4])";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(userQuerySentence);
  System.out.println(matcher.matches());
  while (matcher.find()) {
     String quarterString = matcher.group();
     userQuerySentence = userQuerySentence.replaceAll(quarterString,
              (quarterString.substring(0, quarterString.length() - 1) + " " + quarterString.substring(quarterString
                       .length() - 1)));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[q|qtr|qtrs|quarter]` is a character class, I guess you want `(q|qtr|qtrs|quarter)`:

```
String regEx = "(?i)\\b((?:q(?:trs?|uarter)?)[1-4])\\b";
```

Comment: M42 my string will be like this "Ficoscore for Q1 2005" from this i have to change the string as "Ficoscore for Q 1 2005" but with above regex nothing get matched.

Comment: use `(?i)` case insensitive modifier at the first.

Comment: @M42 i think you don't mind the edit. And also the lang seems like java, so you need to escape \ one more time.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Thanks for edit, I just wanted to do the same when I saw Prasanna's comment.